# Incorrect Author showing

Tags: bug, status-norepro

This might have been noted before, but for instance on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236295/executing-a-method-dynamically) the home page shows the incorrect author as Mr. Skeet. Mr. Skeet just edited the question.

Comment: To extend on Jeff's answer a bit: compare http://stackoverflow.com/ to http://stackoverflow.com/questions (Hence, `status-bydesign` I'd say.)

Comment: Found this thread when I wanted to report the same issue. My attention was drawn to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613629/version-control-as-a-web-application), because it would have been asked by Pekka according to the overview. But it isn't, Pekka just edited it. It seems that the front page does show the last activity, while /questions shows the author. Makes sense, but I think it's confusing, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no-repro -- I see the author as kerido on the SO home page currently.

Note that

- in some views, we do show the owner of the last activity of the question (editor/answer) in that slot, and the homepage is one of those views (since the homepage is ACTIVE, so last activity is what is most relevant)
- Jon skeet also answered the question so he would show up there, too.